# Fluid Mechanics about Hydrostatic Pressure

Tags: fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering, pressure, hydrostatics, water-pressure

[image]

The rectangular gate will open authomatically, when the depth of water becomes
very large. What is the minimum value of d that will cause the gate to just open?
The width of the gate is 2 m.

Comment: This looks like homework or an exam / test question. Show what you have done so far.

Comment: I used for a formula F= (specific weight x h x A).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hydrostatic pressure can be divided into constant part causing a force per width $\rho\cdot g\cdot h\cdot d$ plus linear part with force per width $\rho\cdot g\cdot \frac{h^2}{2}$, where $h=3m$ is the height of the gate. The constant part can be replaced by a force acting in the center of the gate, so with lever arm $L_1 = h/2-1.35$ above the hinge. The force from linear pressure part will act at the $h/3$ from the bottom, so with a lever arm $L_2 = 1.35-h/3$ below the hinge. When the resulting moment is zero, the moments on the hinge from both forces must be equal:

$$h\cdot d\cdot L_1 = \frac{h^2}{2}\cdot L_2$$

From that:
$$d = \frac{h}{2}\frac{L_2}{L_1} = 3.5m$$

Answer (score -1):

The hydrostatic pressureat any depth, as you said, is

$$p=\rho HA$$

- H the depth measured from the bottom.
- A is the width =2m

the total hydrostaic force apllied at H/3 is a triangular pressure diagram.
$$F_h= \frac{H^2}{2} \rho A $$

the gate will open if the CG of hydrostatic force triangle falls above the hinge.

$$H/3> 1.2+1.35=2.55m$$
$$H\geq 3*255 \geq 7.65$$
$$d\geq (H -(1.20+3)) \geq 7.65-(1.2+3)\geq 3.45m$$

Comment: Aren't we going to use this equation (yp= yc + (Ixc/yc*A))?

Comment: @AyçaArırt, the proof is in the pudding. why don't you plug in the d and see where the hydrostatic force acts?

Comment: Okey i gottcha. Thank u for helping. I appreciated.

Comment: @AyçaArırt, please accept my answer then, so it helps other people looking for this kind of question.

Comment: I did it. Just one more question. Can I solve the this type of questions taking moment?

Comment: @AyçaArırt, of course you can. But it would make it harder!